# excel - extracting value given an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I wanted to get the value in column A which does not have a certain value on column B. For example, in this picture, given the set in column B when grouped using the value in column A, how can I get the values which does not have "4" in each set?

So the answer that I'm looking for is 2000 and 3000 because they do not have "4" in their respective sets in column B.

Is this achievable? I can't wrap around my head if INDEX and MATCH can do this.

Comment: Yup, that was the answer I would have posted :-)

Comment: Will do.........

Comment: Was this meant to search for a specific value in column B and search for any value in column A  missing that value in B? Or was the value an example and would you like to retrieve any value of column A where any of the values of column B is not listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK well I see that @JvdV reached the same answer as me which is always reassuring. I added a test for blank cells so:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A20,(COUNTIFS(A1:A20,A1:A20,B1:B20,4)=0)*(A1:A20<>"")))
```

[image]

You could invert the logic if you wanted to but it's a bit longer:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A20,(COUNTIFS(A1:A20,A1:A20,B1:B20,"<>"&4)=COUNTIF(A1:A20,A1:A20))*(A1:A20<>"")))
```

Comment: I don't how you guys get so adept to these excel pre-made functions so well! You're all so good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(range,A1:B13,
     ca,INDEX(range,,1),
     cb,INDEX(range,,2),
     ua,UNIQUE(ca),
     ub,UNIQUE(cb), 
     all,DROP(REDUCE(0,ub,LAMBDA(x,u,VSTACK(x,ua&u))),1), 
     alla,DROP(REDUCE(0,ub,LAMBDA(x,u,VSTACK(x,ua))),1),
FILTER(alla,ISERROR(XMATCH(all,ca&cb))))
```

This doesn't require the 4 as part of the formula and would work on multiple missing numbers

It takes range `A1:B13` and divides it into `ca` (column A) and `cb` (column B).
And the unique values of these two ranges `ua` (unique values column A) and `ub` (unique values column B).

`all` lists all possible joined combinations of `ua` and `ub`.
`alla` creates the same list, but without joining the `ub` values to the outcome.

If we then filter `alla` where the match of `all` list to joined `ca` and `cb` values throws an error (is missing) you get the required result.

In example below I extended the range and `4000` is missing `1`:
[image]

It repeats the same value if it's missing multiple numbers. Wrap the FILTER in UNIQUE to avoid that if undesired.

You may want to include the missing value as well:

```
=LET(range,A1:B17,     
     ca,INDEX(range,,1),
     cb,INDEX(range,,2),
     ua,UNIQUE(ca),
     ub,UNIQUE(cb), 
     all,DROP(REDUCE(0,ub,LAMBDA(x,u,VSTACK(x,ua&"|"&u))),1), 
     a,FILTER(all,ISERROR(XMATCH(all,ca&"|"&cb))),
DROP(REDUCE(0,a,LAMBDA(b,c,VSTACK(b,TEXTSPLIT(c,"|")))),1))
```

[image]